# Can't use css files in eclipse ee

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I have made a .css file for a html i'm using in a dynamic web project. The css implementation clearly works because if i run the tomcat server from the html i can clearly see the css effect but if i run it from the main project it opens the same html page but without the css effect. How am i supposed to fix this? Do i have to write something into the *web.xml* file ?

This is the link tag in the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Am i supposed to add something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on location of css file. Your path will if css is in same folder as html/jsp file. If it is in sub folder in webcontent folder then use `href="foldername/filename"` if its in root folder then `href="../foldername/filename"`

Comment: it was in the same folder as html file, for whatever reason i restarted eclipse and it worked properly